# jQuery Ajax Save - page is seen/ page flickers

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser

I have the following Ajax code within jQuery that uses a save.php page to save data from a form to the MySQL database:

```
    $('#frmSurvey').append("<input type='hidden' name='page' value='"+$page+"' />"); // NOTE: this is done before the submit.

    document.frmSurvey.submit(); // There is some validation done and then the submit is called

    var url = "save.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#frmSurvey").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });
```

And the HTML:

```
<form id="frmSurvey" name="frmSurvey" action="save.php" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
```

Hope that all makes sense.

I understood that the Ajax call to the save.php page would mean that the users doesn't see the page and it happens in the background.  However, the save.php page still appears in the web address bar for a second or two - is this correct - any way to stop this happening?

Comment: It would be interesting to see the code that *wraps* what you have posted. Perhaps you do this inside a `submit` handler and forget to cancel the default submit action?

Comment: Please post your HTML of the form as well.

Comment: As Jon said, let's see what's calling this function. Your code may specifically be changing the URL. By default this is not the behavior of $.ajax

Comment: Thanks all - have updated the question with further information.

Comment: @Homer_J: Well, you are directly submitting the form just before the AJAX request. In fact the AJAX doesn't happen at all because submitting the form forces immediate navigation to the form `action` URL (the momentary URL change is probably because of [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) done on the form target). Why do you do this?

Comment: @Jon, so I can remove the 'document.frmSurvey.submit();'?  I'm only just learning about the Ajax side of things!

Comment: Thanks @Jon - removed the `document.frmSurvey.submit();` code and re-tested and works a treat - thank you.

Comment: @Jon - if you put an answer in for that - I'll +1 and accept.

Comment: @Homer_J: Added an answer, glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation to another URL happens because you are actually doing a proper form submission just before the AJAX call with `document.frmSurvey.submit();` -- in fact this would prevent the AJAX request from occurring because navigating to the form action URL would stop JS processing from the current page.

If you remove that line your form will be submitted through AJAX without any redirection.